# Setting up GoogleMap in Android app

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to add a googlemap into my app, but I couldn't get it to work.
I'm working with ViewPager on xamarin btw.
Layout:

```
...
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
...
```

My fragment:

```
public class InfoFragment : FragmentV4, IOnMapReadyCallback
{
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.InfoFragment, container, false);

        //Set up google maps coords in infos section
        SetUpMap();
        return view;
    }

    private void SetUpMap()
    {
        if (mMap == null) {
            //((MapFragment)FragmentManager.FindFragmentById (Resource.Id.map)).GetMapAsync (this);

            var mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)Activity.SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.map);

            mapFragment.GetMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    //Launching of the actual map
    public void OnMapReady (GoogleMap googleMap)
    {

        //Setup cords and stuff...
    }
}
```

During the setup of my map. When i do

```
var mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)Activity.SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.map);
```

it always returns null. can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

should be:

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

and in my fragment instead of:

```
var mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)Activity.SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.map);

            mapFragment.GetMapAsync(this);
```

it should be:

```
((SupportMapFragment)ChildFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.map)).GetMapAsync(this);
```